# Multiple animations on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I am trying to make my progress bars on my website animate on scroll. So I managed to get a progress bar to animate on scroll. My problem now is that I have multiple progress bars to animate (Danger, warning, success) etc. Do I have to create new elements ? here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/as2gv/11/

```
    // Check if elem is in viewport
 function isElementInViewport(elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);

  // Get the scroll position of the page.
   var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
  var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  // Get the position of the element on the page.
  var elemTop = Math.round($elem.offset().top);
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
 }

// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation(elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);
  if ($elem.hasClass('start')) return;
  if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
  $elem.addClass('start');

  //animated progess bars
  var bar = $('.progress-bar-warning');
  $(function () {
      $(bar).each(function () {
          bar_width = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow');
          $(this).width(bar_width + '%');

          });
      });


  }
}


// Capture scroll events
 $(window).scroll(function () {
 checkAnimation($('.progress-bar'));
 });
```

Would you guys know how to make the all the progress bars animate on scroll ?

Answer (score 2):

did some fixes on your functions and here we go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/as2gv/13/)**

```
  // Check if elem is in viewport
  function isElementInViewport(elem) {
      var $elem = elem;

      // Get the scroll position of the page.
      var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
      var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
      var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

      // Get the position of the element on the page.
      var elemTop = Math.round($elem.offset().top);
      var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

      return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
  }

  // Check if it's time to start the animation.
  function checkAnimation(elem) {
      var $elem = elem;
      if ($elem.hasClass('start')) return;
      if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
          $elem.addClass('start');

          //animated progess bars
                  bar_width = $elem.attr('aria-valuenow');
                  $elem.css('width',bar_width + '%');
      }
  }


  // Capture scroll events
  $(window).scroll(function () {
      $('.progress-bar').each(function(){
          checkAnimation($(this));
      });
  });
```